# STM32F4 DSP noise with inbuilt ADC and DAC

Tags: adc, stm32, noise, dac, dsp

I'm trying to perform signal filtering with STM32F407VGT. I've set up the ADC and DAC to work synchronously, triggered by a timer at 42kHz, and using DMA. The idea is to process half of the buffer while ADC is filling the other half. However, even without any processing, I'm getting a periodic noise in my signal(picture attached). Seems like some portion of the buffer is always messed up. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I'm also attaching the relevant sections of my code here.
Both ADC and DAC operate in 12bit mode and are triggered by Timer2. Both use DMA in circular mode.

```
    #define DATASIZE            64
    #define FULLBUFFSIZE        128

    uint32_t adc_val[FULLBUFFSIZE];
    uint32_t dac_val[FULLBUFFSIZE];
    static volatile uint32_t* inbuffPtr;
    static volatile uint32_t* outbuffPtr;

    void process_DSP()
    {
        for (int n=0; n<DATASIZE; n++)
        {
            outbuffPtr[n] = inbuffPtr[n];
        }
    }

    void HAL_ADC_ConvHalfCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {
        inbuffPtr = &adc_val[0];
        outbuffPtr = &dac_val[DATASIZE];
        process_DSP();
    }

    void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {
        inbuffPtr = &adc_val[DATASIZE];
        outbuffPtr = &dac_val[0];
        process_DSP();
    }

    int main(void)
    {
      HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
      HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *) adc_val, FULLBUFFSIZE);
      HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t *) dac_val, FULLBUFFSIZE, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
      .
      .
     }
```

[image: Noisy DAC output]

Comment: Just my hunch and not enough for answer. HAL functions are known to be slow so problem could be that your buffer isnt long enough. What are you seeing isnt noise, but probably buffer updated too late. Another problem is linked to first in that you dont know actual delay between ADC and DAC sampling. So you need longer buffer.

Comment: Please include your full code. For instance, interrupt initializations are missing. At 42 kHz and with DMA interrupts firing every 64 samples, we’re talking about 1.5 ms between each interrupt, so it’s quite unlikely the buffer is insufficient in this case. Most likely there’s an actual error in the code that can’t be fixed by simply increasing buffer size.

Comment: I fixed it. Somehow at half complete and full complete interrupts, the DAC pointer should point to the same buffer index as the ADC pointer. It fixed the issue but I don't know why.
@swineone I didn't declare interrupts explicitly. ADC and DAC are linked to the update event interrupt of Timer2 and I did it from CubeMX directly.